# Select item matched in the middle in ReactBootstrapTypeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

In my ReactBootstrapTypeahead component, I can click any option to select it, but using <kbd>Tab</kbd> will only select the first option if it matches at the start of the string. If the first option is matched in the middle, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> merely moves the focus without selecting an option. It *does* work if you first use the arrow keys to highlight the option.

[image]

Each option contains an `id`, `make`, and `model`, and I combine the last two into `name` (e.g. `'Toyota Prius'`) for use by `labelKey`. Everything works except selecting the first item without highlighting it using the arrow keys.

```
<AsyncTypeahead
    id="search"
    selectHintOnEnter
    labelKey="name"
    filterBy={startsWith}
    renderMenu={renderMenu}
    options={results}
/>
```

I'm using a custom `renderMenu` function to group options...

```
const renderMenu = (results, menuProps) => {
    const items = [];
    let makesHeader, lastMake, idx = 0;
    results.forEach(result => {
        const { id, make, model } = result;
        if (!make) {
            // skip "click to load more..." text
            items.push(
                <Menu.Header key="more-header">
                    More Results Hidden…
                </Menu.Header>
            );
        }
        else if (!model) {
            if (!makesHeader) {
                items.push(
                    <Menu.Header key="makes-header">
                        Makes
                    </Menu.Header>
                );
                makesHeader = true;
            }
            items.push(
                <MenuItem key={id} option={result} position={idx}>
                    <WordHighlighter search={menuProps.text}>
                        {make}
                    </WordHighlighter>
                </MenuItem>
            );
        }
        else {
            if (make !== lastMake) {
                items.push(
                    <Menu.Header key={`${make}-header`}>
                        {make}
                    </Menu.Header>
                );
                lastMake = make;
            }
            items.push(
                <MenuItem key={id} option={result} position={idx}>
                    <WordHighlighter search={menuProps.text}>
                        {model}
                    </WordHighlighter>
                </MenuItem>
            );
        }
        idx++;
    });
    return <Menu {...menuProps}>{items}</Menu>;
};
```

...and highlight only matches at the start of any word.

```
const WordHighlighter = props => {
    const search = props.search.toLowerCase(),
        len = search.length,
        parts = [];
    let count = 0;
    props.children.split(' ').forEach(word => {
        if (word.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)) {
            parts.push(<mark className="rbt-highlight-text" 
                             key={++count}>{word.substr(0, len)}</mark>);
            parts.push(<span key={++count}>{word.substr(len) + ' '}</span>);
        }
        else {
            parts.push(<span key={++count}>{word + ' '}</span>);
        }
    });
    return <span>{parts}</span>;
};
```

Comment: It seems that an item is only selected by pressing `Tab`(or in fact also `Enter` or `Right Arrow`) if the item is hinted inside of the input element. Unfortunately a hint is only provided when the item matches from the start. I didn't see any way to override that behaviour. The relevant helper function: https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/src/utils/getHintText.js. Notice that it checks for `bounds.start === 0` to decide if the term should be hinted.

Comment: @trixn Interesting, I never see a hint in the input even when `Tab` works to select the first item. I'll dig in and see if there's a way to override this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by [overriding the Typeahead's `onKeyDown` callback](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/461) with my own.

```
const typeahead = useRef();

const onChange = useCallback(([ result ]) => {
    typeahead.current.getInstance().clear();
    typeahead.current.getInstance().blur();
    history.push(`/cars/${result.slug}`);
}, [ typeahead ]);

useEffect(() => {
    const instance = typeahead.current.getInstance(),
        original = instance._handleKeyDown;
    instance._handleKeyDown = (e, results, isMenuDown) => {
        if (results && results.length && (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            onChange(results);
        }
        else {
            return original(e, results, isMenuDown);
        }
    };
}, [ typeahead, onChange ]);
```